# I need to add timecode to a Quicktime movie from the OS X command line?

Tags: macos, quicktime

I just received a ton of footage that needs to have timecode added to it.  I have an Excel file with clip names and start timecode. I'm looking for a OS X tool or lib that will allow me to add timecode to these QT file via the command line so I can automate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take the [QTKitTimeCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QTKitTimeCode/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app from Apple and convert it to a command line app.